# Voltage difference between two nodes surrounding a source

Tags: voltage, dc, ohms-law, nodal-analysis

In the schematic you can see I have this circuit that includes a branch leading from ground to a 10Ω resistance, a 4V DC source and up to node A. I am trying to solve this circuit using the node method (although it's probably better to try using the mesh method in this case). How to I express I_1 using Ohm's law?[image: The circuit]

Comment: \$I_1\$ is an unknown. So you solve for it. You don't get to write a dependent equation for it. Do you need help seeing that more closely? Also, I prefer nodal. It seems you may, as well. It so, say so.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be school work without an attempted solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework with no attempted solution shown.

Answer (score 3):

Replace all your fixed voltage supplies, set up a ground, and move any voltage supplies on a branch so they are tied to ground. You should be able to get the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Kv1v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From here, the KCL should be pretty easy to develop into two equations and two unknowns. And from there, everything else just falls out.

Comment: Down voting because the questionappears to be off-topic school work, and should have been voted to close.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thanks! It means a lot to me to hear what you see. So sincere thanks for taking a moment to say why. Appreciated!

Comment: If you edit the answer, I will un-downvote. Can't un-downvote an answer after awhile unless it is edited. I know you were trying to be helpful. However it gets frustrating sometimes that we get so many "please do my homework" posts.

Comment: @MathK Not sure what you'd want to see modified. I'm mostly happy that you took a moment to say something. That alone makes me quite happy, actually. If you have anything specific though, I'd be happy to comply (I think.) But I'm lost right now about what about the above bothers you. (Sorry, but it is true.) In any case, thanks. It really means a lot that you write, at all. Again, appreciated.

Comment: The OP asked for a **hint** and that's all that should be given since they show no effort or equations themselves. Providing homework solutions feels good but turns the site into a homework solving service.

Comment: Hmm. If that's a consensus then I'm fine removing the KCL. @MathK are you in concert with Elliot and that thought? Or a different idea?

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I agree with Elliot. However, I am not opposed to you leaving the answer here. I think you understand the policy better now, and you put effort into the answer, so I would happily change my vote to up if you want to leave it.

Comment: @MathK I'm cool either way. The KCL isn't hard and I'm fine removing it from the answer and letting the questioner develop it. Changes made.

Comment: I'm fine with you leaving it.

Comment: @MathK Removed already. I'm fine either way. So call it a day.